# Javascript arrays to CSV

Tags: javascript

You need to write a function that translates a two-dimensional array (array of arrays) into CSV format and return a string.

My code:

```js
console.log(arraysToCsv([[1, 2], ['a', 'b']])) 
console.log(arraysToCsv([[1, 2], ['a,b', 'c,d']])) 

function arraysToCsv(data) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] == 'number') {
      return data[i];
    }
    if (data[i] == 'string') {
      return `'${data[i].join('')}'`
    }
    return data[i].join();
  }
}
```

Checks do not pass for some reason. How do I separate numbers and strings, strings should be in quotation marks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Comment: difficult to understand

Comment: SO is not a homework-doing service! Please ask a specific question on a problem you are encountering. "It doesn't work... make it" is not what SO is for. Please tell us what you have tried, what doesn't work and what question you want to ask specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're testing the value of `data[i]`, not its type.

Replace

```
if (data[i] == 'number')
```

with

```
if (typeof data[i] == 'number')
```